# so ... that clause

Tags: grammar

> I’ve been **so** immersed in my work **that** I missed out many festivals.

Someone says this sentence is grammatical because it's a "so ... that" clause.

But I think it is grammatical even without the "so".

> I’ve been immersed in my work **that** I missed out many festivals.

How do you think about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*So...That* expresses a cause and effect. You can not use this structure without that.

It's structure is: So + adjective/adverb + that

We use so…that (degree adverb) to create a comparison between two things. It is used to underline an action to show that something leads to certain results.

Here you can find a full explanation of the use of So ... that: https://open.books4languages.com/english-a2-grammar/chapter/so-that-vs-so-that/